# How to read multiple (5) huge bigquery tables (approx 500 gb each) and perform join?

Tags: google-bigquery

How to read multiple (5) huge bigquery tables (approx 500 gb each) and perform join ?

I have a query like below: but it is taking forever to run and get's killed at a point.

please help, Thanks in advance!

```
select c.bill_dt , b.billg_acct_num , a.prim_srvc_resrc_id_val , c.prc_plan_grp_cd, c.bill_sect_cd  , c.unit_qty , lkp.target_category, 
c.net_chrg_amt, c.disk_amt,ifnull(d.adj_amt,0) + ifnull(e.tax_sum_amt,0) as adjAmt, b.tot_due_amt, b.tot_tax_inv_amt
from (select bill_dt,bill_doc_id,billg_acct_num,tot_due_amt,tot_tax_inv_amt 
       from `dataset.document_dtl` 
       where DATE(bill_dt) > DATE_SUB(DATE(CURRENT_DATE()), INTERVAL 18 MONTH))b 
left join `dataset.chrg_dtl` c
   on --b.bill_dt = c.bill_dt  and 
   b.bill_doc_id = c.bill_doc_id and DATE(c.bill_dt) > DATE_SUB(DATE(CURRENT_DATE()), INTERVAL 18 MONTH)
   and c.prc_plan_grp_cd in ('PREM','AIR','SERV','LCL','LD_WA','LD','LCL','RO')
   and c.bill_srvc_instnc_id is not null
left join `dataset.instnc` a
 on --b.bill_dt = a.bill_dt and 
 b.bill_doc_id = a.bill_doc_id AND DATE(a.bill_dt) > DATE_SUB(DATE(CURRENT_DATE()), INTERVAL 18 MONTH)
left join `dataset.adjmt_dtl` d 
 on --b.bill_dt = d.bill_dt and 
 b.bill_doc_id = d.bill_doc_id AND DATE(d.bill_dt) > DATE_SUB(DATE(CURRENT_DATE()), INTERVAL 18 MONTH)
left join `dataset.adjmt_tax_sum` e
 on --b.bill_dt = e.bill_dt and 
 b.bill_doc_id = e.bill_doc_id AND DATE(e.bill_dt) > DATE_SUB(DATE(CURRENT_DATE()), INTERVAL 18 MONTH)
join `dataset.reference` lkp 
 on lkp.prc_plan_grp_cd = c.prc_plan_grp_cd and lkp.usg_event_srvc_lvl_cd = c.usg_event_srvc_lvl_cd;
```

Answer (score 0):

One tip I can give looking at the query is using partitioning on DATE(c.bill_dt) ,  DATE(a.bill_dt), DATE(d.bill_dt) and DATE(e.bill_dt) -

in all of these conditions you are checking the data for past 18months, DATE(a.bill_dt) > DATE_SUB(DATE(CURRENT_DATE()), INTERVAL 18 MONTH)

so you can create bigquery table partition on all those tables . example:

```
CREATE TABLE
  dataset.dataset.chrg_dtl(bill_doc_id INT64, transaction_date DATE)
PARTITION BY
  DATE_TRUNC(bill_dt  , MONTH)
  OPTIONS (
    partition_expiration_days = 3,
    require_partition_filter = TRUE);
```

and then you can use this partition table in your query similar to this ->
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#query_a_time-unit_column-partitioned_table

and then for these values prc_plan_grp_cd in ('PREM','AIR','SERV','LCL','LD_WA','LD','LCL','RO') you could create clustered tables something similar

```
   CREATE TABLE dataset.dataset.chrg_dtl
    (
      bill_doc_id STRING,
      prc_plan_grp_cd NUMERIC
    )
    CLUSTER BY
      prc_plan_grp_cd 
    AS (
      SELECT * FROM mydataset.unclustered_table
      where .prc_plan_grp_cd in ('PREM','AIR','SERV','LCL','LD_WA','LD','LCL','RO')
    );
```

hope this helps.

Comment: tried, didn't work :(